# iOS7 tableview cell.imageview extra padding?

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I have a tableview which renders perfectly in iOS 6 & has done so for years. In iO7 in the same tableview either side of the cell.imageview its adding some extra padding approx 5mm either side of each image shown below thus moving my cell.textLabel.text further to the right. How would I remove this I cant seem to find the answer anywhere to this question?

[image: iOS image]

Comment: to have total control over rendering, you'll need to ditch the built in cell styles (e.g. UITableViewCellStyleDefault) and roll your own layout.

Comment: Thanks @CSmith so a customCell is the only way to fix this moving forward?

Answer (score 9):

In iOS7, the `UITableViewCell`'s predefined property `imageView` is **indented towards right by 15pt** by default.
And this has **nothing to do** with the following `UITableViewCell` properties

```
indentationLevel
indentationWidth
shouldIndentWhileEditing
separatorInset
```

Therefore creating your own custom `UITableViewCell` is the best way to overcome it.
[According to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18), there are 2 good ways to do it:

> If you want the cell to have different content components and to have these laid out in different locations, or if you want different behavioral characteristics for the cell, you have two alternatives:
>
> - **Add subviews** to a cell’s content view.
> - Create a **custom subclass** of UITableViewCell.

---

### Solution:

As you don't prefer subclassing `UITableViewCell`, so adding custom subviews is your choice.
Simply creates your own image view and text labels, and add them through code or through storyboard. e.g.

```c
//caution: simplied example
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //get the cell object
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    
    //create your own labels and image view object, specify the frame
    UILabel *mainLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 220.0, 15.0)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:mainLabel];

    UILabel *secondLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, 220.0, 25.0)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:secondLabel];
    
    UIImageView *photo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(225.0, 0.0, 80.0, 45.0)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:photo];
    
    //assign content
    mainLabel.text = @"myMainTitle";
    secondLabel.text = @"mySecondaryTitle";
    photo.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
    return cell;
}
```

Note that as the predefined `UITableViewCell` content properties: `cell.textLabel`, `cell.detailTextLabel` and `cell.imageView` are **untouched** so they will remind `nil` and will not be shown.

---

### Reference:

A Closer Look at Table View Cells
https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1

Hope this help!

Answer (score 6):

I probably had the same problem, the only thing that workd for me is setting the image frame:

```
cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 50, 55 );
```

And if you are subclassing the cell, better to do:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 50, 55 );
}
```

Comment: many thanks but setting the frame still makes no difference for me. I still have the padding either side of my images in the table :-(. I suppose I could subclass the cell but seems like a hammer to crack a nut!