# tableview image not appearing properly - iOS 8 iPhone App Objective C

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, uitableview

I am creating a simple tableView with two NSArrays. First array contains titles and second one contains image names. Everything is working fine. But line separators appear with some space after images in tableview (see first screenshot) while it should appear without spaces (like second screenshot).

[First Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Duw9Q.png)

[Second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLUA6.png)

I tried different methods but getting same issue (Tested on iOS 8 device).

What am I doing wrong ?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [dataSourceArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// "Cell" is the default cell identifier in a new Master-Detail Project
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


  cell.textLabel.text = [dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//get UIImage image Names from imageArray
cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];



return cell;
}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103155/ios7-tableview-cell-imageview-extra-padding

Comment: Thanks. My problem was solved by adding custom subviews.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your image .. 
maybe your not using constraints or your cell is small you need to set the height of the cell to view the image.

Comment: In first screenshot, green square is my image (sample image that I am using). Size is 44x44 and height of tableview cell is also 44.

Comment: sorry i can't see the image .. did you used 

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];

Comment: Yes, cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; where imageArray contains imageNames

Comment: you can use for that. NSDictionary 

    NSDictionary *dicName = [self.arrayScreen objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [dicName objectForKey:@"name"];
    cell.imageView.image  = [UIImage imageNamed:[dicName objectForKey:@"nameimage"]];

Comment: Thanks Jeff for your time and help. I truly appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

try to use NSDictionary

```
NSMutableArray *item;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

 self.item = [NSMutableArray array];

NSDictionary *item1 =  @{@"dicNameItem":@"NameItem",@"dicImageItem":@"ImageItem"};
[self.arrayScreen addObject:item1];

}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.arrayScreen count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellScreen" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *dicName = [self.arrayScreen objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [dicName objectForKey:@"dicNameItem"];
    cell.imageView.image  = [UIImage imageNamed:[dicName objectForKey:@"dicImageItem"]];

    return cell;

}
```