# UITableViewCell's backgroundView is offset from the left edge of the UITableView

Tags: ios, ios7, uitableview

When I set the cell's `backgroundView` with a `UIImageView`, there is space on between the left side of the `UITableView` and the left edge of the `backgroundView`. Why is this?

Here's the code that sets the background within a subclass on `UITableViewCell`:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        NSString *imageName = @"invite_bg";
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 502)];
        self.backgroundView = imageView;
        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    }
}
```

[image: Notice that the photo is offset.]

Comment: Is there any space in the image that you are loading?

Comment: @Maverick No, there's no space in the image.

Comment: @ill_always_be_a_warriors add screenshot for watch your problem .

Comment: @DarshanKunjadiya Just did.

Comment: Indeed, out of the box, there's a 15pt inset on UITableView. You can witness this behavior in the Storyboard UI.

Comment: yes @remus is right .

Comment: @remus Can I shift it the background image by 15px back to the left?

Comment: @ill_always_be_a_warriors you could, but the proper solution is to figure out which separatorInset you need to adjust.

Comment: @remus Tried (separately) setting the `separatorInset` to `UIEdgeInsetsZero` for both the cell and the TableView. Neither worked.

Comment: @ill_always_be_a_warriors so try shift it the background image by 15px back to the left.

Comment: @DarshanKunjadiya Using what property?

Comment: CGRectMake(-15, 0, 335, 502) change like that your imageview frame

Comment: Oh snap! It's probably this that's the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982347/uitableviewcell-in-ios7-now-has-gaps-on-left-and-right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was setting the image on `self.imageView` instead of `imageView`. I added the `imageView` as a subview to `contentView`, and it works now!

Answer (score 3):

Use this code

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7.0)
{

}
else
{
   _tbl_time.separatorInset=UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

Hope this useful for you.

Comment: I just tried setting the `separatorInset` on both the TableView and the TableViewCell. Neither worked.

Comment: @ill_always_be_a_warriors add screenshot and some code